# Parse or verify username and email before reseting password

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to reset my User's password by verifying their Email **and** Username. Parse only provides you with an Email check. I am trying to verify the User's Username too before proceeding.

My code is not working. I know it is because I set the password to `nil` but I do not know any other way.

If anyone knows another way, it would be great if you could help me out, thanks.

```
self.stringEmailAddress = [self.outletEmailTF.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
self.stringUsername = [self.outletUsernameTF.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

if ([self.stringEmailAddress length] == 0 || [self.stringUsername length] == 0) {

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Make sure you enter a valid Username & Email Address" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

} else {

    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:self.stringUsername password:nil block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {

        if (user) {

            [PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:self.stringEmailAddress
                                                       block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                                                           if (succeeded)
                                                           {
                                                               NSLog(@"Reset Successful!");
                                                               self.outletEmailTF.text = @"";
                                                               self.outletLabel.text = @"Password reset has been sent!";
                                                           }
                                                           else
                                                           {
                                                               NSLog(@"Reset Unsuccessful!");
                                                               self.outletLabel.text = @"Email Address unrecognized!";
                                                           }
                                                       }];

        } else {

            NSLog(@"No good!");
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it by trying to log a user in without a password. Instead, do a query for a user with the specified email address and username and check how many results you get.

You shouldn't really need to check the username as the password reset is by email, and if the users email is compromised then so is the username...